# PDO object cant acess inside function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my project i had a file called `connection.inc.php` which is managing the data base connection using PDO.

**include/connection.inc.php**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "college";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

i included this file in various other pages and it worked perfectly for me. But when i tried to acess the `$conn` object inside a function it not working. How to fix this problem.

Comment: You must pass it as a parameter.

Comment: How to pass it as parameter?

Comment: [How to pass it as a parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: See my answer for [how to pass it as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36063881/4802649).

Answer (score 2):

You could do `global $conn` on top of your functions, but don't. I suggest wrapping it in a singleton instead.

```
<?php
class Connection {

    private static $conn = null;

    private $connection = null;

    private function __construct() {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "college";

        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage(); // Should look into a different error handling mechanism 
        }
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
        if (self::$conn === null) {
            self::$conn = new self();
        }
        return self::$conn->connection;
    }

}
```

You can access it via `Connection::getConnection()`

This also has the advantage of not initializing the connection if the current request doesn't need to use it.

Comment: Nice approach! Classes are indeed better and more DRY friendly than the procedural way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your file as

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "college";
   //// define global variable
   global $connection

 try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   /// assign the global variable value
   $connection = $conn ;
 // set the PDO error mode to exception
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }

 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Now you can call it any of your function like

```
function mytest(){
     global $connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the simplest method is to set the connection inside of a function then you can use that function in other functions.

Example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function dataQuery($query, $params) {
$queryType = explode(' ', $query);

// establish database connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}

// run query
try {
    $queryResults = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $queryResults->execute($params);
    if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
        $results = $queryResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
    $dbh = null; // second step to close the connection
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
    echo $errorMsg;
}
}
```

How To Use In Another Function:

```
function doSomething() {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `table`';
    $params = array();
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    return $results[0]['something'];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**The best practice would be to pass the `$conn` as argument to the function.** 
But if you really need the function to have no arguments but still use a global variable, then adding this line in your function before using the variable should do the trick:

```
global $conn; // I want to use the global variable called $conn
```

Comment: Using global is rarely the answer, and certainly isn't good practise

Comment: Yeah this is not the best practice.